# Xhtml Transitional Popups

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, xhtml

```
<a href="https://link" location="yes" resizable="yes" scrollbars="no" width="592" height="740" target="_blank">
```

does not validate as location, resizable, and scrollbars are all not valid xhtml - what is the replacement for these terms nowadays?

Comment: I should make a quick note; I know to do width/height as css, its the other ones I am curious on

Comment: I don't think those "attributes" have /ever/ been a part of any HTML spec, other than href and target...

Comment: @mori57 perhaps, but they work and do what they are supposed to, so -shrug-

Comment: I wasn't able to get that html to do anything in Chrome, other than open another URL in a new tab. What browser supports those attributes? I'd be cautious about trusting attributes that can't validate, and don't have widespread standards support. It's true that you could prepend "data-" (ie. "location" would become "data-location") to each of those attributes, and those would be valid and readable in HTML5, but they still wouldn't automatically do anything without supporting Javascript to read them and parse them into a window.open() call. Just my $.02.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JS.

But if you worry about usability, then just leave the link as a normal one, without the extra attributes and let the user decide what he wants to do. If you make clear in the content that the link is more appropriate for a new window, then the user most probably will open it that way.

If you care about usability but still want to force the decision on the user, you may use JS but with event detection and check if the user clicked the link, then capture the url and open it in a new window/tab. If you choose this way, the link will be something like this:

```
<a href="destination" rel="external" >text</a>
```

Of course you can use any attribute, but that one is accepted as a best practice so far.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing new windows via Javascript brings you plenty of headaches, not the least of which are the prevalent pop-up blockers employed by most modern web browsers.

A better way of dealing with links like this is to "decorate" them via CSS with icons that hint at the link's destination, or a javascript alert (if you must... this is also incredibly intrusive on the user's experience) that warns the user they are navigating away from your site to an external source.

Smashing magazine has a decent article on this: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/13/the-definitive-guide-to-styling-web-links/

The technique PatomaS refers to can be seen with code examples, here, though they use a class, instead of looking at rel:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/add-offsite-link-icon-after-external-links-css/

To do the same thing, but with rel, you could change their css to:

```
a[rel="external"] {
    background: url(/images/external.png) center right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 13px;
}
```

However, you should note that this CSS will not work in some browsers.